# Vietnamese hat lost passing Security at DXB - 2nd March,2016

Tags: transit, dxb, lost-luggage

Yesterday (2nd March) I arrived at Dubai Airport in flight EK375 from Bangkok- at 1:10 pm. I had a connection flight to Lisbon (EK193) boarding at 1:55pm. 
While passing the x-ray/Security on my way on foot to B26, between flights, I lost my "Vietnamese hat" with a purple ribbon hat. I realized thi swas lost when I arrived inside the plane - but I couldn't go back due to lack of time for departure. It was very meaningful to me! (Not for its price but it was a gift really special to me).

Can you check if you found it in lost and founds or if it was kept by someone in x-ray, please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a specific request.

Comment: This is an attempt to communicate with a specific airport/airline, and not an appropriate question for the SE network.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt anyone from Dubai Airport is following this forum, so will not hear your plea.

But they do have a phone number you can call or a form you can submit: https://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/baggage/lost-found

Comment: And this isn't a forum.